# HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() in Tomcat returns IPv6 formatted IP address

Tags: java, tomcat, ipv6, windows-7-x64, ipv4

HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() in Tomcat returns IPv6 formatted IP address, but I would like to configure it that returns IPv4.

I access the servlet via 'localhost'. If I access it via '127.0.0.1' then returns IPv4 formatted IP address (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020303/tomcat-log-format-disable-the-ipv6-format/4021201#4021201)).

Environment:

- Windows 7 x64
- Tomcat 6.0.35-windows-x64

My LAN connection properties:
**IPv6 is checked off**, but it doesn't work neither if I check it on.

[image: My LAN connection properties]

Comment: mmm... we have 2012. IPv6 becomes more and more popular, and you disable it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try adding this parameter `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to your tomcat startup commandline.

Answer (score 0):

when you use localhost/xxx, your browser first have to find the mapped address for the name "localhost".In system host file you will find:

> # 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> # ::1             localhost

both definition disabled by default.

to change browser's default matching rules, you have to enable the definition.

e.g: remove "#" from the first host file line, your brower will know directily "localhost" equals 127.0.0.1

Cheers