# IP Address in Java and JSF

Tags: java, jsf, ip

I am using the following code to get the IP address form a client.

```
public String getIp(@Context HttpServletRequest requestContext, @Context SecurityContext context) {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
    if (ipAddress == null) {
        ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
    return ipAddress;
}
```

However, when it executes, it returns `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`. It is running on my local pc, and I would expect it to return good ol `127.0.0.1`. Any ideas why not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting IP address of client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558869/getting-ip-address-of-client)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The question is not about getting the IP address, but about why it is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` is an IPv6 IP address. You need to ensure you set it to IPv4 if you want only the IPv4 response. See @Javier's answer.

Answer (score 1):

> However, when it executes, it returns 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1. It is running on my local pc, and I >would expect it to return good ol 127.0.0.1. Any ideas why not?

If the machine is behind a proxy you won't be able to get it's local IP or domain information, in any server side technology

Refer
[1] [Getting IP address of client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558869/getting-ip-address-of-client)

Answer (score 1):

Your machine has dual stack (IPv4/IPv6). The `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` address (also written as `::1`) is the IPv6 equivalent for localhost.

Comment: Best to provide the details how to set it to capture only IPv4 info ;)

Comment: The server should be bound to an IPv4 address, otherwise it listen on every address, and IPv6 is given preference.

Comment: Right, but you can choose to bind only to the ipv4 interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is late but for those who will visit this page in the future. If you are running Tomcat, you may set `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable and add

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

and

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true
```

In eclipse it maybe added in:

> Debug As -> Debug configuration -> Environment.