# How to get Source IP of Request in Json with Annotation?

Tags: java, json, resteasy

Am trying to get request source ip with annotation @JsonProperty("IP") which not populating values.

Hi , I wrote web application using ResteasyBootstrap to receive and process http request with post parameters. ex: client send the product details in post parameters to server url. below is the sample

```
@Path("/json/Product")

public class Prodcut {

@POST

@Path("/post")

@Produces("application/json")

public Product getProductInJSON(Product product) {

           System.out.println(product.toString());


    String respMsg=processProduct(product);// process product

    product.setResponseMessage(respMsg);

     String JsonRespString=new Gson().toJson(product);

    return Response.status(201).entity(JsonRespString).build();

}

    public class Product{


 @JsonProperty("name")

  private String name;

   @JsonProperty("msgid")

      private String msgId;

/*setters gettes */

  @Override

public String toString() {

    return "{\"msgid=\":\"" + this.msgId + "\" , \"name\":\"" + this.name +""/
```

}";
}

now how do i get ip of client.
Suggest me

Comment: You're going to have to work on your question. Add some context. What does the JSON look like? How are you deserializing it?

Comment: JSON is a data format. It's used for exchanging data (sending and receiving) in a simple and clearly defined format. It has no notion of an IP address. (Clarify your question please)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the client IP, then use the `@Context` to get the request. Then something of what is here: [Getting IP address of client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558869/getting-ip-address-of-client)

Comment: Given the `@JsonProperty` and the fact that it is tagged `json`, I think they are trying to get the JSON field named `IP`.