# App engine request headers for ip address

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, servlets, request

I have an app engine application that runs REST web services. 
I want to extract the ip address from all requests that are handled by my web services.

from javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest i'm trying to extract the ip address checking the "X-Real-IP" , if empty or "unknown" check the first ip in the list of "X-Forwarded-For" header if empty or "unknown" get it from request.getRemoteAddr().

I thought i covered all the cases but i'm still getting ip addresses like 10.x.x.x, or 127.0.0.1 or unknown.

I know that app engine applications are running behind load balancers, and instances are dynamic and i'm certainly omitting a header in the request cuz i can see the original ip address in the logs (from google) .

Edit : all the requests i'm working on are direct request to service (no queue or cron requests).

Any idea of the other headers to check ?

thx .

Comment: internal requests (cron, queue, etc) are coming from `10.x.x.x` btw

Comment: thx for answering, but i'm talking about direct calls (no cron or queue calls) .

Comment: Are you using cloud endpoints? if so it'd make sense for you requests not to have original IP.

Comment: i'm not using endpoints, i have a rest webservice exposed using Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answeres of [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558869/getting-ip-address-of-client) might help you. There are a lot of headers to check for:

```
private static final String[] HEADERS_TO_TRY = { 
    "X-Forwarded-For",
    "Proxy-Client-IP",
    "WL-Proxy-Client-IP",
    "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR",
    "HTTP_X_FORWARDED",
    "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP",
    "HTTP_CLIENT_IP",
    "HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR",
    "HTTP_FORWARDED",
    "HTTP_VIA",
    "REMOTE_ADDR" };
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. i will log all these headers with and without the `HTTP_` in production in the next app release and will check where the real client ip address is stored. In addition to the linked answer i may add to check `ipAddress.startsWith("192.") || ipAddress.startsWith("192")`  to avoid   local network ip addresses. I'm pretty sure that my mistake is that i'm checking `X-Real-IP` and  `X-Real-IP` before `request.getRemoteAddr()`. i'll accept the answer if i find out it's linked to this.