# Getting client static IP address

Tags: java

I am deplyong a web application in the Internet and I am checking whether the user's login is valid by checking its client IP address (e.g. *192.168.2.XXX*). Actually, I have found a working code (below). This code was completely working before, but after some time, its output is not the same anymore. Now, this code only gives me 1 IP address which is the server's IP address. What is wrong with my code? How can I get the client's static IP address rather than the server's IP address? I have also tried other solutions such as `getRemoteAddr()` and `request.getHeader("PROXY-CLIENT-IP")` but it is not working.

Java:

```
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
if(ipAddress == null)
    ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting IP address of client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558869/getting-ip-address-of-client)

Comment: Because the first time, your request header had an IP so `ipAddress` was not null and you got the client IP. second time, it was null and it went inside the `if` branch and gave you the localhost's (server's) IP.

Comment: None of the answers in the link above works

Comment: @VivekVK Yes, the first line is giving me the client's IP address but it is not the static one. How can I get the client's IP address that starts with *192.168.2.XXX*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are mixing two levels of abstractions and that is rarely a good thing.
The header [X-FORWARDED_FOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) is inserted by a load balancer or proxy. If the client reaches the server directly, then this header isn't present and you are executing this code `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();`. Which does exactly what you say: It is retrieving the IP address of the host where this piece of code is running, i.e. the web server.

See also here: [Getting the client IP address: REMOTE_ADDR, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, what else could be useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527638/getting-the-client-ip-address-remote-addr-http-x-forwarded-for-what-else-coul)

Comment: Does this mean that there is no way to get the client's IP address regardless of it being unreliable?

Comment: You write that you need this for login purposes. Don't use IP addresses for authentication purposes. It's not too difficult to fake IP addresses, through a proxy, for example. It's better to have the user send her/his credentials explicitly, i.e. as part of the HTTP message.

Comment: I am actually also asking for credentials but I want to limit the logins of the users by them, only being able to login on their respective computers (IP addresses)