# How can I find the IP address of a client running a stored procedure under QZDASOINIT on iSeries.

Tags: stored-procedures, websphere, ip-address

through a 3rd party vendor, we have a WebSphere application that calls a stored procedure which runs SQLRPG program to update DB2 from this job I have been asked to execute another webpage from the SQLRPG to the PC the stored procedure was executed from before the job ends. Have tried looking for the IP but everything we have tried returns the iSeries server IP address where the job is running and we need where was called from.  any ideas?  iSeries OS 6.1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly.

1- Client send a reques1 to a WAS App1 running on IBM i V6R1.
2- The app calls a stored procedure which I assume you have freedom to pass
   additional parameters to, you just need the client's IP address.
3- You then want to make a call from the stored procedure to the client IP that made the HTTP request to the WAS App1.

The IP address can be obtained from the Application App1 code using the
HTTP request parameter passed into the servlet. 
   I found is a good discussion of how to get the IP address in the following stack overflow link :
[Getting IP address of client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558869/getting-ip-address-of-client).

Please post if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

run the command `netstat` then take option(3) to see the IP addresses of clients connected to the iseries.