# How to get system IP using log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

My project is in cluster form and while using `logger.debug`, I want to know which system has received the request and when I check logs, I should also see system IP as a parameter in logs.

When we use log4j2, inside log file you get time & name of class.

```
[DEBUG ] 2018-03-05 01:16:43.233 <className>
```

In this line I also want to know system IP.

Comment: You might want to read about MDC http://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be the possible duplicate of [Getting IP address of client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558869/getting-ip-address-of-client) the below code can be used  print the ip Address.hope it helps to an extent

```
 Something like this:
 MDC.put("ip", PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request).getRemoteAddr() );
 MDC.put("user", request.getRemoteUser());

 With appender configuration:
 <appender name="MY_APPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%X{ip}][%X{user}][%c{1}:%L] %m%n" />
    </layout>
 </appender>
```

refer :https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/18089322#_19_message_18089322

Comment: To avoid coding, I want to know how we can get system IP using log4j2

Comment: you can add appender as above @Tatkal

Comment: @Tatkal - I expect that you will find that you can't avoid having to do some coding.  But hey ... why is coding a problem for a Java programmer like you?

Comment: @StephenC coding is not a problem for me. Right now I am in chaos.

Comment: So you why are you trying to avoid coding, if it is not a problem for you?   As I said, you probably can't avoid it anyway.  So by *trying* to avoid it, you are actually making your life *more* difficult,