# Retrieving Clients IP Address in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to get a user IP address from asp.net web API application.
I am using angular 6 and asp.net web API. My API always returning the angular application's hosted IP address, not the user IP address. Below is the sample code which I am using

```
string HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR))
{
    var s = HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR.Split(',');
}
string REMOTE_ADDR = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Comment: You use Angular but your question is about ASP.NET. I'm removign the Angular tag as to not pollute the Angular board.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558869/getting-ip-address-of-client

Comment: @KristófTóth I am looking for .net solution not java.

Comment: Yes but i think its pretty straightforward, it's just not copy pastable you have to think it through